# texlive shell escape problems with psfrag

Tags: texlive, eps, shell-escape

I work with some scripts that automatically convert the fonts in a plot using psfrag and pstool to another font.

However these fail if I use texlive. They work with Miktex.
Since I get requests from Linux users to make the scripts work on Linux I would like to know better why I get these problems.

The script is based on Matlab. If you are interested in all details see [svn source](http://code.google.com/p/latexfigure/) and [explanation/documentation](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/blog/2010/10/11/matlab-figures-solving-export-problems/).

The code that is created is like this one

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[]{pstool}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
   \centering
   \psfragfig{TEMP9134}
\end{document}
```

with the Figure file *TEMP9134*, which contains all psfrag calls

```
\providecommand\matlabtextA{\color[rgb]{0.000,0.000,0.000}\fontsize{14.5}   
{14.5}\selectfont\strut}%
\psfrag{011}[cl][cl]{\matlabtextA Validation Data}%
\psfrag{012}[cl][cl]{\matlabtextA Fit}%
\psfrag{013}[cl][cl]{\matlabtextA Model}%
\psfrag{014}[cl][cl]{\matlabtextA Data}%
```

for this [eps file](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/files/extern/TEMP9134.eps)

- If I call the main tex file with pdflatex from miktex with enabled shell escape everything works.
- If I call the main tex with pdflatex from texlive without enabling shell escape no error occurs, because the pstool package disables itself without shell escape.
- If I I call the main tex with pdflatex from texlive with enabling shell escape TeX stops with the error

  (c:/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))"
  (./pstool-statusfile.txt)Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
  ! Missing number, treated as zero.

The corresponding log file is more informative

```
(./pstool-statusfile.txt)
runsystem(cd "./"& del "pstool-statusfile.txt" )...executed.
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
```

pstool-statusfile.txt contains this

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (Web2C 2011)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
"^^%ERRORLEVEL^^%"
```

Here I have no clue what is going wrong actually. 
Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: With TeX Live 2011 on a Mac I get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`del` is not a Unix command ; you should use `rm` on Unix-like operating systems. You may want to use the `ifplatform` package to detect the platform.

Comment: I have not looked at the code of the package, but the error message is from *windows*.

Comment: This Question and [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60084/pstool-pdflatex-not-getting-pstool-to-work-latex-error-file-not-found] are related to each other.

Comment: With the latest Texlive 2012, the pstool with psfrag is working well both Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04. No issues of any sort. Although i have not checked with Miktex 2.9.